# Linkbutton in ASP.NET MasterPage and child Webform data control creating extra href=""

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, repeater, href, linkbutton

EDIT Final:  Just in case someone else sees this behavior, I wanted to explain my work around.  I was using a placeholder on my Master page for the webform described below.  I added a server control to the placeholder in the Master page OnInit event.  Through a process of elimination, I figured out that the behavior described below only happens when I add this server control to the Master page.

```
titlebarPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(sctitlebar)
```

I re-wrote the Master Page to not need the server control added and the behavior described below went away.  I have no idea what caused it.  It was a simple server control, but this is my work around.

EDIT 2:  The same behavior happens when the container is a table in the repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAuditList" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="odd">
           <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOpenAudit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("auditname") %>'></asp:LinkButton> </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>  
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<td><a href="" id="contentMain_rptAuditList_lnkOpenAudit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$contentMain$rptAuditList$ctl00$lnkOpenAudit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Demo PreClose July 2012</a> </td>
```

EDIT: In my testing I just noticed that if I run the extact same control OUTSIDE of a MasterPage, it worked correctly, but if I run it inside a MasterPage, it behaves in the way described below.

I have tried this with a Repeater, DataList and Listview and the results are always the same.

Here is the HTML:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwAuditList" runat="server" >
<LayoutTemplate>
<ul><li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></li></ul>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAudit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("auditname") %>' >            
</asp:LinkButton></li>
</ItemTemplate>               
</asp:ListView>
```

Here is the output:

```
    <ul>
<li><a href="" id="contentMain_lvwAuditList_lnkAudit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$contentMain$lvwAuditList$ctrl0$lnkAudit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Demo PreClose July 2012</a></li>
 <li><a id="contentMain_lvwAuditList_lnkAudit_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$contentMain$lvwAuditList$ctrl1$lnkAudit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Demo PostClose Audit June 2012</a></li>
 </ul>
```

The first row always has an extra href="" added.  I have never seen this behavior before.  I have stripped down the html and code behind to its most basic, yet I still get this extra href="".    The code behind just sets the datasource and binds it, nothing else.

Thank you.

Comment: its created by server to do post back......on click of link

Comment: yes, but why are there two href=""'s?  One is for the postback, but the second one is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the first list tag as a placeholder and replacing the content in the code behind I would use a slightly different approach adding an ASP.NET PlaceHolder inside the list tag as follows:

```
<ul><li><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" /></li></ul>
```

I have experienced some unusual artefacts appearing in Response code when using ASP.NET tags in a manner for which they were not particularly intended. This may well be causing your problem as well!

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I will test this out.  I have moved back to using a table in a repeater as I believe the issue has to do with the Master page.  I will update the initial post with the Table html also.